# Unexpected Output For C Program For Int Datatype

Tags: c, types

Can anyone explain why the output is not as expected ?
I was  expecting 16 but got 14.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x=016;
    printf("%d",x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `016` means octal number.

Comment: What was expected?

Comment: Were you expecting 16 but got 14?

Comment: You should use `%o` to print octal numbers — not `%d`. Octal numbers start with a `0` on input. To get a leading zero on output, you need `%#o`.  See [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html) and [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html). _(And yes, this is a very tongue-in-cheek comment — it is accurate up to a point, but it is also very misleading. There's no way to decide whether `x` contains an octal or decimal value; it really contains a binary number and the formatted I/O functions control the appearance.)_

Answer (score 4):

Numeric literals beginning with 0 are interpreted as octal numbers.

> 6.4.4.1 Integer constants
>   3 ... An octal constant consists of the prefix 0 optionally followed by a sequence of the digits 0 through 7 only. ...

E.g `016`(8 base) ==> `0` x 8^2 + `1` x 8^1 + `6` x 8^0 ==> 0 + 8 + 6 ==> `14`(10 base)

`%d` of `printf` outputs the value of `int` in 10 bases, so the result is `14`.

If you output `int` as an octal number using `%o`, `16` is obtained.

E.g

```
int x = 016;
printf("%#o", x);//016
```

If you want results with three digits include leading `0` using `%d`,

```
printf("%03d", 16);//016
```

Please refer to the reference of [printf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) for details of format string.

Comment: Thanks for helping out.